# get time from DS1307 in Setup() and Loop()

Tags: arduino, real-time-clock

I am implementing a DS1307 in a project using the DS1307RTC library and have 2 questions:

1. Initialisation of the DS1307RTC happens automatically. This seems to prevent use of the library in my own library. Why is this implemented like this? and can it be "overruled"?
2. I can get time and date from the DS1307. But, if I do this in the setup(), I can not do it again in the loop(). Why is this? does this has to do with question 1? I do not have this problem with other libraries or with my own libraries.

Comment: Your question cannot be answered without your code including "my own library".

Comment: For question 2 this might be true, although other libraries work fine in a self created library. I will add some code.